# .htaccess : the simplest redirect produces too many redirections

Tags: .htaccess

this is my simple rule in .htaccess (I want to redirect that only 1 url to its https version):

```
Redirect /gateway.php https://www.example.com/gateway.php
```

but this gives me

> net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an infinite redirect there. Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule gateway\.php https://www.example.com/gateway.php [R=302,L]
```

Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` loaded.